# How to convert a twiiter link into an embedded tweet?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, string, twitter

I am building a news website which gets data from an external server. The external server often sends me the links to particular tweets but I can't seem to find a way to convert them into an embedded tweet
(Please note stack overflow wont let me send shortened urls, therefore it is in quotations.)
The json that it sends me is like -

```html
"Story": "ROME: Harry Kane scored twice as a buoyant England cruised through to the semi-finals of Euro 2020 with a one-sided 4-0 win over Ukraine in Rome on Saturday. Kane ended a worrying international scoring drought by netting in the 2-0 last-16 defeat of Germany in midweek and he put England ahead inside four minutes on a sweaty evening in the Italian capital. <a href="https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/football/euro-2021/ukraine-vs-england-live-score-uefa-euro-2020/liveblog/84098469.cms"><strong>As it happened: Ukraine vs England</strong></a> Gareth Southgate's side then put this quarter-final tie out of sight with two more goals early in the second half, one from Harry Maguire before Kane netted again. Substitute Jordan Henderson got the fourth, and as Denmark lie in wait in the Wembley semi-final on Tuesday England will be confident of going on to reach a first ever European Championship final and even now claiming a first major international title since 1966. <p>�������������� England = semi-finalists ������#EURO2020 | #ENG https://twitter.com/EURO2020/status/1411427976047120387"</p>&mdash; UEFA EURO 2020 (@EURO2020) <a href="https://twitter.com/EURO2020/status/1411430018262224897">1625346114000</a> The draw here was kind for them, with Ukraine surely as weak an opponent as they could hope to face in a quarter-final, a stage at which they have lost to the likes of Italy and Portugal in recent European Championships. However the statistics are impressive, with England having come through five games at this tournament all without conceding a goal. Some of their play in wide areas was outstanding, with Raheem Sterling and Jadon Sancho -- making his first start at the Euro -- too hot for Ukraine to handle. <p>⏰ RESULT ⏰What. A. Performance. �������������� Kane (2), Maguire & Henderson net in Rome as England reach EURO 2020 se… https://twitter.com/EURO2020/status/1411427976047120387"</p>&mdash; UEFA EURO 2020 (@EURO2020) <a href="https://twitter.com/EURO2020/status/1411427976047120387">1625345627000</a> Kane, their captain, had gone close to eight hours without finding the net for his country but his opener here was his second in just eight minutes following the late strike that secured victory over Germany. Regardless of the opposition, their display at the Stadio Olimpico was a step-up in class in the final third to previous games at the Euro and they will be favourites at home against a Danish side who played their own quarter-final against the Czech Republic on Saturday in distant Baku. This will be the only match England play away from home in the competition and it marked quite a difference to their defeat of the Germans, which was watched by more than 40,000 supporters at Wembley, where coronavirus restrictions were eased. <p>�������������� Two-goal England hero Harry Kane takes the plaudits after inspiring the Three Lions in Rome ��@Heineken |… https://twitter.com/EURO2020/status/1411427976047120387"</p>&mdash; UEFA EURO 2020 (@EURO2020) <a href="https://twitter.com/EURO2020/status/1411431548386172934">1625346478000</a> With Italy currently imposing a five-day quarantine on all arrivals from the United Kingdom, the number of England fans in Rome was limited to those already based in the European Union although they still made themselves heard in the crowd of under 12,000. They had plenty to celebrate, unlike their Ukrainian counterparts, as Andriy Shevchenko's team came up short in their bid to take the country to a first ever major tournament semi-final. They scraped out of their group and then edged 10-man Sweden in extra time in the last 16, and their chances of shocking England looked dead and buried when they fell behind early on. Sterling, who terrorised the Ukraine defence down the left, played in Kane who poked the ball past Georgiy Bushchan. Ukraine's giant striker Roman Yaremchuk forced a save from Jordan Pickford and a Declan Rice piledriver was kept out by Bushchan, with England looking comfortable. However Ukraine were a different proposition after injured defender Serhiy Kryvtsov was replaced by Dynamo Kiev winger Viktor Tsygankov in the 36th minute. They finished the first half strongly and more pessimistic England fans may have spent the interval reliving their exit from Euro 2016, when they lost to Iceland in the last 16 despite also having opened the scoring in the fourth minute. They need not have worried. England scored again less than a minute after the restart when a foul on Kane allowed Luke Shaw to deliver a free-kick from the left for Maguire to head in. Four minutes after that Sterling supplied the overlapping Shaw and he crossed for a rejuvenated Kane to head home. The Tottenham star nearly had his hat-trick, a stinging volley producing a fine save from Bushchan. From Mason Mount's resulting corner came the fourth goal, another header, this time from Henderson, the first of five substitutes sent on by Southgate who would have been thinking about the semi-final long before this quarter-final was officially over. ",
```

Edit: Based on the reply below this. Let me clarify My server sends me data in the form of json objects with strings in it. I pass this data using ejs tags to their appropriate location to get rendered. I am asking how can i convert every twitter url that winds up in my json object to an embedded tweet.

Edit: This is the json that i received from the server I can render that just fine on my webpage but i cant seem to find a way to convert the hyperlinks to embeded tweet

Comment: It would help if you explain how https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/how-to-embed-a-tweet doesn't already cover this. You know the tweet's id (141143....) so just take the iframe embed src and use id of the tweet you need embedded.

Comment: Thats the problem I cant tap into what my server gives i just took it from an already rendered web page

Comment: My server sends me data in the form of json objects with strings in it. I pass this data using ejs tags to their appropriate location to get rendered. I am asking how can i convert every twitter url that winds up in my json object tp an embedded tweet.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you. Twitter provides an api for creating embed html from a tweet url.

```
const axios = require('axios');


const main = async () => {

    const tweetURL = 'https://twitter.com/thejackbeyer/status/1411522480775204866?s=20';

    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?url=${tweetURL}`);
        console.log(response.data.html);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}


main();
```

Comment: Thanks but when I tried this it showed me this error:- Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: You need to stick everything inside the try/catch inside an async function. I will update my code sample to show. You should be able to drop the whole thing into a new file and run it.

Answer (score 0):

just add "https://publish.twitter.com/oembed?" before your url as mentioned [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/embedded-tweets/overview).
you can also customize the embedded tweet as described in the link.

the response would be something like

```
{
  "url": "https://twitter.com/Interior/status/507185938620219395",
  "author_name": "US Dept of Interior",
  "author_url": "https://twitter.com/Interior",
  "html": "<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Happy 50th anniversary to the Wilderness Act! Here&#39;s a great wilderness photo from <a href="https://twitter.com/YosemiteNPS">@YosemiteNPS</a>. <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/Wilderness50?src=hash">#Wilderness50</a> <a href="#">pic.twitter.com/HMhbyTg18X</a></p>&mdash; US Dept of Interior (@Interior) <a href="https://twitter.com/Interior/status/507185938620219395">September 3, 2014</a></blockquote>n<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>",
  "width": 550,
  "height": null,
  "type": "rich",
  "cache_age": "3153600000",
  "provider_name": "Twitter",
  "provider_url": "https://twitter.com",
  "version": "1.0"
}
```

and you can use the html property as embed tweet.